# How do I deal with an HTTP 410 when web scraping?

Tags: php, http, web-scraping

I can access a web site through my browser, for example:

https://waset.org/conferences-in-february-2020-in-london

... but if I try and web scrape this web site (I am using php simplehtmldom), I get an HTTP Error 410 (which means the page is gone, but it is there as I can see it through my browser).

Other web sites (from the same family, e.g. https://waset.org/conferences-in-february-2021-in-london), I can scrape just fine.

Does anybody know why I get a 410, when the web page is there, and what I can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even crawl it. Chrome also get `410` error code:

[image]

Continue your stuff like if it was `200` code.

-- Edit --

Look at this code it works well for your page :

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),
));

$result = file_get_contents('https://waset.org/conferences-in-february-2020-in-london', false, $context);

var_dump($result); 
// output <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" dir="ltr" id="desktop"> <head> <!--Google Tag Manager -->...
```

We only choose to ignore errors, like our browser do automatically.

Comment: Thank - not sure how to continue (as if 200), as the HTML does not load (as far as I can tell). I also don't think that I cam trap the error with the SimplePHPDOM package - but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page in a browser, the server responds with a `410` as well – see attached imag. They probably want to convey the message that the conferences are expired.

[image]

The rest of the data is loaded as expected...

Comment: Yes - I think they do want to convey that the conferences is expired, but the only difference I can see in the HTML (when I look at page source) is the addition of the "expired ribbon". Not sure how the 410 error is raised.

I recognise I am naive in this, but if I can see it in my browser, not sure why 'file_get_html' will not work.